# Autohotkey tabs differently through web form

Tags: autohotkey

When I tab through form manually from key board it's goes through very systematically and in order but when I set it up using
    Sendinput {tab}
It takes a different tab route.  I do notice it seems to take alternate route after leaving a combobox.  How can I keep the tab order as if I'm tabbing manually

Thanks all

Comment: Does the combobox change the next options in the form around (showing or hiding some bits)? If so, is there any chance AutoHotkey is sending tabs too quickly, and the browser isn't ready - and adding some delay to AutoHotkey between tabs so it runs at slower human speed might help?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler no comboboxes do not activate a brayed out text box based on any specific selection made. It's weird I made a script that only tabs through form. For example tab then sleep etc so I could watch order. And it's a different order from when I tab through manually on key board

Comment: I'm puzzled, but interested. Key presses and AutoHotkey should be sending similar messages to the browser window. Have you tried other browsers (FireFox, Chrome, IE) and do they do the same? Can you post your AutoHotkey script to show how you're selecting the browser window (if at all) and in case there's some interaction with other keys in it?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler  im using IE and this is the script to get active window -----  Winactivate, ahk_class IEFrame
im going to try firefox to see if same result happens thanks for suggestion ill let you know

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler  worse result in firefox - I cant even manually tab through one textbox, no idea why but it is a masked phone field and firefox makes me mouse click to move on, tab doesnt work at all in it.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler  worse result in firefox - I cant even manually tab through one textbox, no idea why but it is a masked phone field and firefox makes me mouse click to move on, tab doesnt work at all in it.